# Jquery How to push data key into array from start

Tags: jquery, arrays

I m pushing data from jquery classes into array. This runs pretty nice. But if I want to put more keys to an array it counts on. And don`t starts from 0

Thats how it should look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [postenart] => 1
            [netto] => 0.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [postenart] => 0
            [netto] => 0.00
        )
)
```

My Code:

```
var daten = [];
$(".postenart").each(function(i) {
    var data = {};
    var postenart = $(this).val();

    data.postenart = postenart;
    daten.push(data);
});
$(".netto").each(function(i) {
    var data = {};
    var netto = $(this).val()
    data.netto = netto;
    daten.push(data);
});



<input type="hidden" class="postenart" value="1">
<input type="hidden" class="netto" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" class="postenart" value="0">
<input type="hidden" class="netto" value="2.00">
```

Comment: Sorry im not following whats the expected output

Comment: @jstuartmilne for some unknown reason the OP used PHP's awful array notation. From the context it appears they want something like this: `[{"postenart": 1, "netto": 0},{"postenart": 0, "netto": 0}]`. However without seeing the associated HTML we can't help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. If the structure of your HTML is always as you provided, this will work:

```js
$(function() {
  var daten = [];
  $(".postenart").each(function(i, el) {
    daten.push({
      postenart: $(el).val(),
      netto: $(el).next().val()
    })
  });
  console.log(daten);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="postenart" value="1">
<input type="hidden" class="netto" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" class="postenart" value="0">
<input type="hidden" class="netto" value="2.00">
```

This iterates over each element with the class `postenart` and places the value for that element, and the value of the next element into an Object that is then pushed into the array. **The caveat** is that if the HTML structure is different or does not have the same organization, you may collect a value from an unexpected element.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution before. But I just put this small html code as a example. Normaly code is bigger and there have to be more keys in array. Thats why I want to take "each" function everytime. Otherwise I have to use .find and .closest and stuff like this

Comment: Please edit your post and include a more proper example. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example